# I can't break blocks in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know the basics: left click is attack, right click is use. I do *not* have my game on adventure mode, it is on peaceful survival. I do not have cheats on either.

When I put my cursor on something, it doesn't even "highlight" the block like it normally does. If I hold down the left mouse button, it hits once and then stops moving. There are no mining animations nor breaking down of blocks. Essentially nothing happens.

I've checked my settings a million times, and I have restarted the game at least twice. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: A very dumb question: are you standing close enough to the block to reach it? Otherwise you could try reinstalling minecraft.

Comment: You can also open your world to LAN with cheats and try to put yourself in survival gamemode. Just to be sure.

Comment: *"I do not have my game on adventure mode"* - how are you checking this?
 Keep in mind the world's default gamemode (shown on world screen) isn't necessarily the gamemode the player is currently in. What's happening to you sounds exactly like adventure mode.

Comment: Make sure that you are close enough to the block.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, especially on multiplayer servers, blocks in the spawn region can't be modified (presumably this is to prevent griefing).  If you move about ~100 blocks away, the blocks will behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're near enough, on Survival, and have your cursor aimed on the block. If not, it's a serious issue, and possibly a bug, so start a new world in this case.